# Show that $\overline \varphi (a Z (D_4)) = Id$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

Consider $$\begin{align}\overline \varphi : \frac{D_4}{Z(D_4)} &\to \frac{D_4}{Z(D_4)} \\aZ(D_4) &\mapsto xax^{-1}Z(D_4)\end{align}$$

where $$D_4 = \{id, \alpha, \alpha^2,\alpha^3,\beta,\alpha\beta,\alpha^2\beta,\alpha^3\beta\}$$ is the dihedral group of order $8$, $Z(D_4)$ its center and $x \in D_4 - Z(D_4)$.

**Question:**

Show that $\overline \varphi = Id$.

**Attempt:**

Take any $aZ(D_4) \in \frac{D_4}{Z(D_4)}$. Notice that

$$\begin{align}aZ(D_4) =  xax^{-1}Z(D_4) &\iff ay = x a x^{-1}, x \in D_4 - Z(D_4)\\&\iff a^{-1}xax^{-1} \in Z(D_4)\end{align}$$

As $Z(D_4) = \{e, \alpha^2\}$

$$a^{-1}x a x^{-1} = e \iff ax = xa \iff a \in Z(D_4)$$

or $$\begin{align}(a^{-1}x a x^{-1})(a^{-1}x a x^{-1}) = e &\iff [(ax)(xa)^{-1}]^{-1} = (ax)(xa)^{-1} \\&\color{red}\iff ax = xa \\&\iff a \in Z(D_4)\end{align}$$

With this in mind we have

$$\begin{align}\overline\varphi (aZ(D_4)) &= xax^{-1}Z(D_4) \\&= xx^{-1}aZ(D_4) \\&=aZ(D_4)\end{align}$$

Therefore $\overline\varphi = Id$.

1) Is it correct?

2) I don't know if the  red part is valid.

3) Is there a faster way to show this?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not valid. $a^2=e$ does not imply $a=e$. Even in $D_4$ it is not true I'm afraid. The condition and conclusion is right here though.

$\overline{\phi}=\mathrm{Id}$ just means that the quotient group is commutative. Also note that $$D_{2n}=\langle r,s |r^n=s^2=e, s^{-1}rs=r^{-1}\rangle$$ or in your notation it means $\alpha^4=\beta^2=e,\beta^{-1}\alpha\beta=\alpha^{-1}$, and the commutator subgroup is generated by $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}$ which is exactly $\alpha^2$. So here $[D_8, D_8]=\mathrm{Z}[D_8]$, and the quotient is naturally commutative.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I didn't say that $a^2 = e \implies a = e$. How would you show that $a \in Z(D_4)$.?

Comment: @AaronMaroja, maybe with some special relations in $D_4$, but it is essentially exhaustion of the properties and elements of $D_4$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $D_4/Z(D_4)$ is a group of order 4 (in particular, its the Klein 4-group), and thus abelian. The map in question is simply conjugation in an abelian group, so it is the identity.